# Setting autosize mode for TextView has no effect

Tags: android

I'm setting autosize using Compat like everyone does:

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(this, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM)
```

And when I read the value afterwards

```
TextViewCompat.getAutoSizeTextType(this)
```

It's 0 (No Autosize) and test, naturally, does not scale.

I'm not using android layout (I set the position and size on my own), but even if I set LayoutParams just to not let them be empty, it has no effect. Any hints?

Comment: where do you get the values

Comment: I'm using my own layout logic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I only need to use AppCompatTextView instead of TextView :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use two way either use in XML or in programmatically.

**Methode 1:**
use the attribute:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

**Methode 2:**

or using `setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes(int[] presetSizes, int unit)`
in `oncreate` methode

Make sure Your your attribute width is `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

```
    add this app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" in your TextView.
```

> Or

```
In XML, we can do it by adding these lines in our TextView

    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize=”100sp” 
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize=”12sp” 
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity=”2sp” 
    app:autoSizeText=”uniform”
```

> Or, in Java

```
    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(TextView textview, int autoSizeMinTextSize, int autoSizeMaxTextSize, int autoSizeStepGranularity, int unit); 

    // Example
    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(myTextView, 12, 100, 2, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
```